# SharePoint 2013 REST - Possible to Upload accross Site collections with embeded code or NAPA? SP.AppContextSite 403

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, rest, json, cross-site

Has anybody been able to REST Upload cross site/domain of a file to a document Library with REST on SPO 2013 thru embedded page code or NAPA? Wondering how app security is set on the TargetSite?  I can do it to a doc lib on the same site, but cross gives me 403 - Denied. User has full control to both sites.

Here's my code. Note the two URLs /sites/dev vs /sites/test

```
    function PerformUpload(fileName, fileData) {
    var url;

    //var path = appWebUrl; var p = path.split('/');var approot = p[0]+"//"+p[2]+"/"+p[3]+"/"+p[4];


        url = 'https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev' +
        "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@Target)/web/lists/getByTitle(@TargetLibrary)/RootFolder/Files/add(url=@TargetFileName,overwrite='false')?"+
          "@TargetSite='" + 'https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test'+ "'" +
            "&@TargetLibrary='Documents'" +
            "&@TargetFileName='CV" + fileName + "'";
            alert(url);



$.ajax({     
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()

        },
        data: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'Title': 'New title' }),


        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        binaryStringRequestBody: true,
        body: fileData,
        success:successHandler,
        error: errorHandler
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a cross domain policy file on the Document Library that you are connecting to.

Here is an article explaining how to do this.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/11/29/solving-cross-domain-problems-in-apps-for-sharepoint.aspx

```
// Load the cross-domain library.
$(document).ready(function () {
var hostweburl;
var appweburl;

//Get the URI decoded URLs.
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(
    getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
    );
appweburl = decodeURIComponent(
    getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl")
    );

// Load the .js files using jQuery's getScript function.
$.getScript(
    hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js",
    continueExecution);

// After the cross-domain library is loaded, execution
//  continues to this function.
function continueExecution() {
    var executor;

    // Initialize your RequestExecutor object.
    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

    // You can issue requests here using the executeAsync method
    // of the RequestExecutor object.
}

// Function to retrieve a query string value.
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params =
        document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I missed it, but the article does little on how to implement it. Please note this is on SharePoint Online and My code is embedded into a page, so no VS or NAPA deployment is going on. Also, I googled "implement a cross domain policy file on a SharePoint Document Library" and found very little.

Comment: I don't know much about SPOnline but I know this article is solving the exact issue you are describing in the exact environment. You have to use the SPExecutor object to perform your requests on the site.